# accessing the navigation controller from separate delegate class

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

I am follwing a tutorial from a book and there the delegate and datasource are separated from the controller (MyViewController.m)

```
[self setDataSource:[[MyViewDataSource alloc]
[self setDelegate:[[MyViewDelegate alloc]
```

for understanding, I now want to pop a controller from the delegate class (MyViewDelegate.m)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        2ndViewController *controller = [[2ndViewController alloc]];
        [[self navController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

of course this will not work since the navcontroller sits in the app delegate. But how do I best access the navcontroller from the delegate class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
UINavigationController *navController = [(MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] navigationController];
```

However, you should ask yourself why you need to do this and if there is a better way that is more in keeping with MVC (model view controller) and the rules of encapsulation.

For instance, `UIViewController` presents a property named `navigationController`, which, as explained by the documentation, will return the appropriate navigation controller for the given view controller.

Comment: Yes, if your delegate class is distinct from your view controller, and needs access to the nav controller, a better approach is to set a property on the delegate object when you initialize it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies!
The only reason I wanted to do it was to get it working by the tutorials way...